# Exposing functions, structs, and type aliases to Godot 4 with GDExtension?

Tags: c++, godot

I'm messing around with Godot 4 and GDExtension, trying to hook up some C++ code. Right now, I'm a bit stuck because I can't find any good examples on how to expose not just classes, but functions, structs, and type aliases. Here's what I got:

**register_types.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "register_types.h"
#include "../godot-cpp/gdextension/gdextension_interface.h"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/class_db.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/defs.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/godot.hpp"
#include "cards.hpp"

void initialize_gdextension_types(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level) {
  if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_CORE) {
    return;
  }
  // TODO: register my functions and structs
  // TODO: figure out how to do it
  godot::ObjectDB::register_object<Error>(); // <- no member named 'register_object' :)
}

void uninitialize_gdextension_types(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level) {
  if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_CORE) {
    return;
  }
}

extern "C" {
// Initialization
// NOTE: I don't think we need to touch anything here
GDExtensionBool GDE_EXPORT
poker_utils_library_init(GDExtensionInterfaceGetProcAddress p_get_proc_address,
                         GDExtensionClassLibraryPtr p_library,
                         GDExtensionInitialization *r_initialization) {
  godot::GDExtensionBinding::InitObject init_obj(p_get_proc_address, p_library,
                                                 r_initialization);
  init_obj.register_initializer(initialize_gdextension_types);
  init_obj.register_terminator(uninitialize_gdextension_types);
  init_obj.set_minimum_library_initialization_level(
      godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_CORE);

  return init_obj.init();
}
}
```

**cards.hpp:**

```cpp
#ifndef CARDS_H_
#define CARDS_H_

#include <string>
#include <variant>

struct Error {
  std::string message;
};

using CardIndexResult = std::variant<int, Error>;

CardIndexResult getCardIndex(const std::string &card);

#endif // CARDS_H_
```

I tried the `godot::ObjectDB::register_object<Error>();` thing, but no dice. So, how do I:

1. Get the `Error` struct into Godot?
2. Make `getCardIndex` callable from Godot scripts?
3. Deal with the `CardIndexResult` type alias?

---

### For future reference

I was able to compile the following:

```
// register_types.cpp
#include "register_types.h"
#include "../godot-cpp/gdextension/gdextension_interface.h"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/class_db.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/defs.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/godot.hpp"

#include "deck.hpp"

void initialize_gdextension_types(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level) {
  if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_CORE) {
    return;
  }
  godot::ClassDB::bind_static_method("@GlobalScope",
                                     godot::D_METHOD("get_deck"), &getDeck);
}

void uninitialize_gdextension_types(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level) {
  if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_CORE) {
    return;
  }
}

extern "C" {
// Initialization
// NOTE: I don't think we need to touch anything here
GDExtensionBool GDE_EXPORT
poker_utils_library_init(GDExtensionInterfaceGetProcAddress p_get_proc_address,
                         GDExtensionClassLibraryPtr p_library,
                         GDExtensionInitialization *r_initialization) {
  godot::GDExtensionBinding::InitObject init_obj(p_get_proc_address, p_library,
                                                 r_initialization);
  init_obj.register_initializer(initialize_gdextension_types);
  init_obj.register_terminator(uninitialize_gdextension_types);
  init_obj.set_minimum_library_initialization_level(
      godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_CORE);

  return init_obj.init();
}
}
```

And this is the defintion of the `deck.hpp` file:

```
#ifndef GODOT_PLUGIN_DECK_H_
#define GODOT_PLUGIN_DECK_H_

#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/godot.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/templates/vector.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp"

godot::PackedStringArray getDeck();

#endif // GODOT_PLUGIN_DECK_H_
```

That function is a encapsulation of my original function, see it here:

```
// deck.cpp
#include "deck.hpp"
#include "../src/deck.hpp"

godot::PackedStringArray getDeck() {
  godot::PackedStringArray cards;
  auto deck = poker::getDeck();

  for (const auto &card : deck) {
    cards.push_back(godot::String(card.c_str()));
  }

  return cards;
};
```

#### However, `get_deck` isn't showing at `@GlobalScope`

The extension is being detected by Godot and loaded, after restarting the editor I went right into the documentation of `@GlobalScope` but `get_deck` isn't showing. **IDK what I'm doing wrong at this point**.

### I saw the mistake, did some corrections and now things work

So I ended making a class to encapsulate my functions, on `register_types.cpp` at the `initialize_gdextension_types` function I put `godot::ClassDB::register_class<Poker>()`. The class itself takes care of registering its methods:

```
// poker.cpp
void Poker::_bind_methods() {
  godot::ClassDB::bind_static_method("Poker", godot::D_METHOD("get_deck"),
                                     &Poker::getDeck);
  godot::ClassDB::bind_static_method(
      "Poker", godot::D_METHOD("get_deck_shuffled"), &Poker::getDeckShuffled);
}
```

Now Godot can see the class and use its methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but for your custom class or struct to be handled by Godot, it has to inherit from Godot's `Object` type (or any other class), since you'll need a few specific member functions for the interaction with the engine (including scripting).

To do this, you have to use inheritance and an extra macro inserting the additional members:

```cpp
class Error: public godot::Object {
  GDCLASS(Error, godot::Object);
}
```

This should allow you to register the class in your initialization function and then pass it around, and create/destroy instances of it:

```cpp
godot::ClassDB::register_class<Error>();
```

If your custom class needs additional members, you'd add a `protected` member `static void _bind_methods();` to your `Error` class, which is then able to use similar `ClassDB` methods to add any callbacks or properties you want to expose.

To bind a global function that's not a member, you can use ``, something like this:

```cpp
godot::ClassDB::bind_static_method("ParentClassName", "getCardIndex", &getCardIndex, godot::String());
```

I'm not sure how to do it with global scope, I think you can pass `"@GlobalScope"` or so, but I've never done it before and can only type from memory right now, so take this note with a grain of salt.

Comment: thanks for the pointer! I have a few questions: 1) the `class Error` would be a "wrapper" around my `Error` struct, used in `GDCLASS` or is the same class passed as an argument to `GDCLASS`?

also, with types aliases I would do the same as you showed with `Error`, they aren't treated different, correct?

Comment: @Mario Probably worth mentioning that the `GDREGISTER_CLASS` and similar macros exist and that `GDCLASS` requires a `_bind_methods()` function to be defined. Additionally godot-cpp is deliberately written in a way that code used for a gdextension can easily be transferred into the engine and vice versa so the engine source code is also a good place to look if you want to know how to do a lot of things.

Comment: @SilicDev I noticed that the documentation on writing modules for Godot mostly applies for making GDExtension, too.

Comment: @Mario if I have a function that returns `std::vector<std::string>` do I have to wrap it with another function that uses Godot's String class? I'm having funny errors like `godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:546:15: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'godot::Variant' and 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >')` during compilation

Comment: TIL I can't come up with types definitions but use those provided by Godot that are compatible with `godot::Variant`, so instead of `godot::Vector<godot::String>` I must use `godot::PackedStringArray`

Comment: I did some findings and expanded my question to add them. Now things work, Godot can access the methods of the class I ended writing to register it with GDExtension. I'm happy!